# Display RDL in C#

Tags: c#, rdl, report-builder2.0

I have an RDL file designed in ReportBuilder 2. I need to show it in my C# application. I know there is an RdlViewer example at gotreportviewer.com but it is not what I really want (For example it can not handle parameters with multiple values). Instead, I'm curious about the way ReportBuilder itself shows report previews. Looking at its installation directory, I found several interesting DLLs. Using ILSpy, I saw that inside MSReportBuilder.exe, there is a method called "StartPreview()" which is called when you the "Run" button in ReportBuilder. Here is the code:

```
private void StartPreview()
{
    try
    {
        if (!this.m_layoutEditor.AtBookmark("ReportPreview"))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                this.m_layoutEditor.CommitPendingChanges(false);
                this.m_preview.Reset();
                Report report;
                if (this.ActiveServer != null)
                {
                    this.m_preview.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                    report = this.m_preview.ServerReport;
                    string text = this.ActiveServer.ServerUrl;
                    if (this.ActiveServer.IsInSharePointMode)
                    {
                        text = Util.RemoveTrailingSlash(text) + "/_vti_bin/reportserver";
                    }
                    AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = this.ActiveServer.GetAuthenticationInfo();
                    if (authenticationInfo.IsFormsAuth)
                    {
                        this.m_preview.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.SetFormsCredentials(authenticationInfo.AuthCookie, authenticationInfo.UserName, authenticationInfo.Password, authenticationInfo.Domain);
                    }
                    this.m_preview.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(text);
                    using (this.m_layoutEditor.UndoManager.BeginTempGroup())
                    {
                        Report rdlObject = this.m_layoutEditor.Report.GetRdlObject();
                        if (this.CurrentReportInfo.IsServerReport)
                        {
                            this.m_reportProject.ResolveServerReferences(rdlObject);
                        }
                        RdlSerializer rdlSerializer = LayoutEditor.CreateSerializer();
                        rdlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, rdlObject);
                    }
                    memoryStream.Position = 0L;
                    this.m_preview.ServerReport.LoadReportDefinition(memoryStream);
                    DataSourceCredentials[] storedCredentialsForCurrentReport = this.GetStoredCredentialsForCurrentReport();
                    if (storedCredentialsForCurrentReport.Length > 0)
                    {
                        this.m_preview.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(storedCredentialsForCurrentReport);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.m_preview.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                    report = this.m_preview.LocalReport;
                    using (this.m_layoutEditor.UndoManager.BeginTempGroup())
                    {
                        Report rdlObject2 = this.m_layoutEditor.Report.GetRdlObject();
                        this.m_reportProject.FixUpDataSourceCredentialsForLocalPreview(rdlObject2);
                        RdlSerializer rdlSerializer2 = LayoutEditor.CreateSerializer();
                        rdlSerializer2.Serialize(memoryStream, rdlObject2);
                    }
                    memoryStream.Position = 0L;
                    this.m_preview.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(memoryStream);
                    DataSourceCredentials[] storedCredentialsForCurrentReport2 = this.GetStoredCredentialsForCurrentReport();
                    if (storedCredentialsForCurrentReport2.Length > 0)
                    {
                        bool flag;
                        this.m_preview.LocalReport.GetDataSources(out flag);
                        if (!flag)
                        {
                            this.m_preview.LocalReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(storedCredentialsForCurrentReport2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                report.DisplayName = this.CurrentReportInfo.ReportName;
                this.m_preview.RefreshReport();
                this.m_layoutEditor.SetBookmark("ReportPreview");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string message;
        this.m_reportProject.ParseException(ex, out message);
        ErrorDialog.Show(this, Strings.Error_Preview, message, ex);
        this.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Design);
    }
}
```

Interesting point is that the code for server-side processing is very clear. But I can't understand how the client-side processing (my need) works! Can you help me do the same thing in my application?

I'm using VS 2010 / .Net 4.0

Comment: I tried to add a reference to "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer.Controls.dll" to use classes defined in it. But when I write "using Microsoft.ReportDesigner" I receive an error. Why and how can I solve this?

Comment: I'm still trying to use these DLLs in my application with no success. I'm sure a lot of people around the world dream of embedding an RDL designer in their applications. I wish we could start a collaboration to do that.